# Copying Arrays to make words

Tags: java

I'm currently learning on how to make programs with arrays. I'm trying to learn how to copy characters such as a-z. I know how to do *copyFrom and copyTo*, but I do not know how to take and pick random letters to form a word such as apple. 
Here is my code:

public class copyarrays {

```
public static void main(String [] args){ 

    char[] copyFrom = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n',
            'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z' };       

     char[] copyTo = java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(copyFrom, 2, 20);

        System.out.println(new String(copyTo));

    }

}
```

I currently have the copyTo and copyFrom in but thats just a little more code to help with visual preferences.

-How would I copy certain characters such as [0] = a [15] = p [15] = p [11] = L [4] = e and it would print out apple?

Comment: You'll need a custom solution. Can't use `copyOfRange`.

Comment: By the way, `copyFrom[13]` contains `'n'`, not `'p'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
char[] randomChars = {
    copyFrom[0],
    copyFrom[15],
    copyFrom[15],
    copyFrom[11],
    copyFrom[4]
}

String output = new String(randomChars);
```

Now `output` will contain the string `"apple"`. There really isn't any other way, because you need random chars from the source `char[]`, and the "copy" methods work only for ranges of consecutive characters.

To make the solution a bit more generic, you could write a helper method that receives an `int[]` with the indexes relative to `copyFrom` and returns a string with the chars in those positions, like this:

```
public String copyRandom(char[] copyFrom, int[] indexes) {
    char[] output = new char[indexes.length];
    for (int i=0; i < indexes.length; i++)
        output[i] = copyFrom[indexes[i]];
    return new String(output);
}
```

This is how you'd use it:

```
int[] indexes = {0, 15, 15, 11, 4};
copyRandom(copyFrom, indexes);
=> "apple"
```

Comment: Works for this example. I suspect OP wanted something more general, but since it's not specified well, this is correct. +1

Comment: Sorry for the delay I have not had time to look. This works great! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be - say you want to create words with 5 letters. Just get 5 letters at random locations from your array and that's all. But this rarely may give you a word that would make sense.

Another way would be - have a dictionary of as many words as possible, say words with 5 letters. Then generate the random string as stated above and check if that exists in your dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

```
copyTo[0] = copyFrom[0];
copyTo[1] = copyFrom[13];
```

and so on..

Comment: You need to make sure you initialize `copyTo` to the right length first.

Comment: This would work for the example of "apple", but for the general case..Well, question needs to be more specific, imo .